# require not working with rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Here is my file, `test.rb`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'pry'
```

There is no problem running it with `ruby`:

```
$ ruby test.rb
```

However, there is an error with `rspec`:

```
$ rspec test.rb
/path/to/test.rb:2:in `require': no such file to load -- pry (LoadError)
```

Versions:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [i686-darwin12.5.0]

$ rspec -v
3.0.4

$ gem -v
2.0.14

$ gem list pry
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
pry (0.9.12.6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

`rspec` was installed using `bundle install`.

`pry` was installed using `gem install`.

I went back and installed `pry` using `bundle install` and now `rspec` runs without error.

I cannot however explain why exactly the failure occurs.  Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Bundler is probably storing/looking for gems in a different location than `gem install`. Unless you have a extremely good reason to, it's better to always use bundler and the Gemfile.

Oh, I also strongly recommend you to install a newer version of Ruby. That should be pretty simple using [RVM](http://rvm.io/).